# Connect to Secure JDBC DB from terminal

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, jdbc

For a normal JDBC connection, we connect to the DB from terminal using below syntax
 `sqlplus USERNAME/PASSWORD@hostname:port/SID;`

How do I connect to a DB with Secure JDBC? This is how the DB Url looks like:

`(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=servername)(PORT=nnnn))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))`